Specific Video Making
I know this may be oddly specific, but answer me these:

How do I make a video out of images where each image lasts for 5 seconds?

I am looping a video where the characters can only say "1! 2!" How do I change the subtitles to make it go from "1!" all the way from "100!"



How would that work for number 1? And as for number two, how do I make sure the timing of the subtitles are correct?

By the way, some of the images 768x1200, and I want to make sure they stay that way with black bars. How do I do that?
